# Android Studio Project not compiling properly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

This is my app gradle -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.projects.nalin.parking"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

This is my project gradle -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

It is showing me error in v23\values-v23.xml file, which I do not know where it came from; as shown in image below -
[image]

Can someone please help me resolve this? Or any redirection to any link will help. I am new at this, and learning Android, so do not know much.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the direct issue, but it looks like you aren't using the latest versions of the build tools, compile sdk version, or any of the support libraries. Try updating those, the resource you're referencing may not be included in the lower version packages you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

Use the v23 SDK if you want to use v23 resources.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

You can still run your code on devices with APIs 13..21

And update all the lines in `dependencies { ... }`

- the `com.android.support` libraries to `:23.2.1`
- the `play-services` to `:8.4.0` (also, not sure why you need all the play-services when you are individually using maps, nearby, and appindexing)

Comment: As I said, I am new at this, and do not know the intricacies. So, I included the whole play-services. So, can you please make changes in my app build gradle, and show me how exactly it should be?

Plus, play services is for accessing Location (I think)

Comment: Yo. atleast till there. What about dependencies version?

Comment: I have a question though. These errors started coming in when I updated my Android Studio. Before that, the code was same, and it worked fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Somehow the `res/values-v23` folder was generated, as so all the error is saying is that it can't find the v23 resources because you are only using v21

Comment: Ok. I made these changes, and now its updating and installing Android Support Repository. Lets see if it works. If it doesn't, I might bug you more.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a style based on V23, yet your targetSdkVersion is 21. Try setting that to 23.

Also, open Android SDK manager and check if there are any updates on AppCompat or anything relevant

Comment: It's the compileSdkVersion, not the targetSdkVersion that matters.